# How to override markPrevious and markNext methods on rich:suggestionBox javascript

Tags: javascript, richfaces, overriding

I have a requirement where users should be able to navigate from the first to the last item in a rich:suggestionBox's list by pressing the  key, and vice versa by pressing the .

I need to get this working on richfaces 3.3.x

The quest to get this done has led me to the javascript that is behind the rich:suggestionBox. You can find it at [JBoss anon svn](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/richfaces/tags/3.3.3.Final/ui/suggestionbox/src/main/resources/org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/suggestionbox.js). The methods in question are *markPrevious()* and *markNext()*.

This is how they are defined on the *Suggestion.Base.prototype* :

```
markPrevious: function() {
    if (this.index > 0) this.index--;
    //else this.index = this.entryCount - 1;
},

markNext: function() {
    if (this.index < this.entryCount - 1) this.index++;
    //else this.index = 0;
},
```

As you can see, the functionality that I need is there, but for some reason they placed it in comment. So I tried to override the methods by placing the following bit of javascript in my template file that is used by all my pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    if(Suggestion) {
        function newMarkPrevious() {
            if (this.index > 0) this.index--;
            else this.index = this.entryCount - 1;
        }

        function newMarkNext() {
            if (this.index < this.entryCount - 1) this.index++;
            else this.index = 0;
        }

        Suggestion.Base.prototype.markPrevious = newMarkPrevious;
        Suggestion.Base.prototype.markNext = newMarkNext;
      }
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Now, if I inspect the *Suggestion* object with firebug, I can see that the methods indeed get overridden. However, all rich:suggestionBoxes on my pages still use the old implementation. So, I'm thinking that somehow, the objects behind the rich:suggestionBoxes get created **before** I override the prototype. And this is where I'm stuck. I don't know how I could get my version in there **before** any of those suggestionBoxes get created.

Has anyone got an idea on how to solve this?

Thanks,

Kim.

P.S. I realise that there is also the option of just adjusting the code directly in the richfaces-ui.jar, but I don't want to have a custom built jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was found by someone over on the richfaces community forum: http://community.jboss.org/message/563271

> You should redefine
>   RichFaces.Suggestion.prototype's
>   functions like this:
>
> if(RichFaces && RichFaces.Suggestion)
>   {
>        RichFaces.Suggestion.prototype.markPrevious
>   = newMarkPrevious;
>        RichFaces.Suggestion.prototype.markNext
>   = newMarkNext; }
>
> Because RichFaces.Suggetsion.prototype
>   extends Suggestion.Base.prorotype's
>   methods before you redifinition.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can place an a4j:support component in that rich:suggestionBox with a javascript onKeyUp event handler that calls a javascript function similar to this one:

```
function KeyCheck(e) {

   var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
   switch(KeyID) {
     case 1:
         markNext function
         break;
     case 2:
         markPrevious function
         break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I think that won't work, for 2 reasons:
1: The rich:suggestionBox doesn't 'refire' the onKeyup event.
2: The markNext() and markPrevious() need to be called on the object itself, and I don't think I can reach it from an a4j:support.